# How do I save a php ZipArchive to a MySQL blob?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, php-ziparchive

I need to save a zip file into my mysql db as a blob. I have created a ZipArchive using

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('test.zip',ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

The zip archive contains several csv files that i am creating and adding to the zip

```
if($file = tmpfile()) {         
fputcsv($file, $headers);
foreach($rows as $row) {
               fputcsv($file, $row);
}
```

The csvs are created fine(checked via debugging). I then add the csvs to the archive using

```
$zip->addFile($file_uri,'file_x');
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to be able to get the zip contents into the mysql blob. I have tried both `readfile('test.zip')` and `file_get_contents('test.zip')` but in both cases I just get the `NAME` of the files inside the zip in (what i assume to be) a compressed format.

I am using cakePHP and the function to create the zip is run from the terminal. Also I cannot alter the table structure in any way. Also is there anyway in which I can get a handle to the the ZipArchive that I have created?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. well actually it was just a really really mistake on my part . Even though I used `$zip->close()` the zip file still persisted on my server. So the older zip files that were empty and just contained the csv filenames were being used instead of the new files that I created.

All I had to do was `unlink('test.zip')` at the end of my code after closing the zip file(which is good practice anyway).

I saved the zip contents into my MySQL blob using

```
$this->MyModel->saveField('data', file_get_contents('test.zip'));
```

Also , be sure to call `$zip->close()` BEFORE the database save. Otherwise  file_get_contents won't work